# Restful web service 415

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-status-code-415

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/uri",produces = "application/json", 
consumes="application/json")
public class VisitorService {
VisitorDAO vis=new VisitorDAO();

@RequestMapping(value = "/ex" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showDetails(@RequestBody VisitorDTO visitor){
    vis.addVisitorEntry(visitor);
    return "success"+visitor;
}}
```

Above is my rest service.
whenever I hit a post using the URL with the below JSON,

```
  {
    "phoneNumber" : 188892,
    "name" : "kikiki" ,
    "email" : "loa@gmail.com",
    "purpose" : "Business",
    "hostName" : "sjs S Murthy"
  }
```

im getting HTTP Status 415 – Unsupported Media Type.
why would that be?

Comment: May be you are missing `Accept: application/json` in the HTTP request?

Comment: how you are calling the rest service, I mean r u using postman?? check your content type there

Comment: nope, sending request through postman, have sent the request ussing application/json header.

Comment: yes , added content type- appplication/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have set the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in a @Configuration class.

Also, try adding the following dependencies to your pom.xml (if not using Maven, just add them to your classpath however you prefer).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version> // 2.4.3
</dependency>
```

Spring uses Jackson and Jackson-databind to parse the request's JSON body into a Java Object.

Comment: have used xml based configuration

Comment: Try adding this to your xml config: `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, and you still need the Jackson libraries in your classpath.